# Get yesterday date according to user input

Tags: codeigniter, date

I want to get the yesterday date according to the user input.I am having the date value on $date variable.I want to get the previous date of the $date variable.I have seen that previous date can be get by this

```
date('d.m.Y',strtotime("-1 days"));
```

But i don't know how to use the $date value here.
Help me to get the previous date of $date variable

Answer (score 0):

`$prev_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));`

**View :**
`<a href="?date=<?=$prev_date;?>">Previous</a>`

This will decrease the date by one from the date you are on at the time.

Comment: I want to use this is in a controller..How can i use it???$prev_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));$result2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM daytot WHERE tdate='$prev_date'")->row_array();..I use like this and it gives null value

Answer (score 0):

ook, Try this code you will definitely Get yesterday date according to user input

```
$old_date = '21-12-2018';
$date = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($old_date . "-1 days"));
echo $date; // OutPut is: 20-12-2018
```

Comment: getting date as 01-01-1970

Answer (score -1):

```
$prev_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date["date"] .' -1 days'));
$result2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM daytot WHERE tdate='$prev_date'")->row_array();
```